# How to delete a specific form from a formset in a view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a formset using a costom model form. The form has a boolean field called "delete". If that field is True the whole form should not be validated, but instead the instance should be deleted.

When the formset is completely valid I just go through all the forms and delete the model instances in question. Then there is a redirect so the user sees a refreshed formset filled with the current data.

But when the formset is not valid I still want to save all the valid forms. So I go through the formset and validate and save all the correct forms. Then I go though all the forms again and delete the ones marked for deletion. But then I don't redirect, but instead print out the template with the request.POST populated formset so the user gets to see forms that are not valid.

Because I don't do the redirect there are still forms which belong to previously deleted model instances.

So how can I delete forms from a formset in the view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform delete/processing of the whole formset when all forms are valid. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32005259/1714030)