# Deleting form from django formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to implement a django formset (where user may dynamically add/remove forms from formset).

I use JS to add new rows (using empty_form):

```
    $("#add-item").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var count = parseInt($('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
        $('.invoice-items').append($('#empty_invoice_item').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, count));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count+1);
        $(".invoice-items .invoice-item .col-lg-9 .form-group:last-child").last().append('<a href="#" class="delete-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>')
    });
```

I also use JS to set DELETE flag on specific forms. Everything is passed to the view.

My view (part) code:

```
invoice_form = InvoiceForm()
invoice_item_helper = InvoiceItemHelper
InvoiceItemFormset = formset_factory(InvoiceItemForm, extra=0, max_num=15, validate_max=True, min_num=1, validate_min=True, can_delete=True)
formset = InvoiceItemFormset()

if request.method == 'POST':
    invoice_form = InvoiceForm(request.POST)
    formset = InvoiceItemFormset(request.POST)
```

The problem is, django always displays all forms in the formset, even those marked for deletion. So, even there is something wrong in my invoice form and it doesn't validate, it will show invoice form with error message AND all forms (once again).

How can I remove completely forms which are marked for deletion in `if request.method == 'POST':` block? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to remove forms marked for deletion after a failed POST, or after a successful POST?

Comment: What django version are you using. Also show the complete code snippet including forms.py and views.py.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's dependent on how you render the forms, but you can check the field 
[form.DELETE](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py#L19) in the template and if it's set, render that form hidden for display and the data will be passed along until the data is processed (when all other forms are valid). It will also make sure form prefixes and indexes for the formset is intact.

When a formset is validated it will ignore forms marked for deletion. [formset.is_valid](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py#L304)

You can also pick up which forms are deleted in the view using [deleted_forms](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py#L213) and perhaps process them, still you will have to rebuild the whole formset without the deleted forms to maintain indexes and the count of forms. 
I personally found out that doing that is complex and leads to complicated code.

Answer (score 6):

Django provides a for-deletion feature which should enable proper deletion of your form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete

The `form-X-DELETE` needs to be set to some value evaluating to true though. The default is `on`, as you can see in the example from the documentation:

```
>>> data = {
...     'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '3',
...     'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '2',
...     'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
...     'form-0-title': 'Article #1',
...     'form-0-pub_date': '2008-05-10',
...     'form-0-DELETE': 'on',
...     'form-1-title': 'Article #2',
...     'form-1-pub_date': '2008-05-11',
...     'form-1-DELETE': '',
...     'form-2-title': '',
...     'form-2-pub_date': '',
...     'form-2-DELETE': '',
... }
```

So if that is not working, perhaps you are not actually sending a value to your `form-X-DELETE`? Do note that you need to specify the actual form data when sending the delete. Simply sending the form number alone is not enough identification for Django to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no method  provide by FormSet to delete a form.