# Forms are not getting deleted from formset after is_valid() check

Tags: python, django

I have forms that can be dynamically added and deleted from a formset. On the front end, I mark deletion by checking the "delete" checkbox included in the form. form-0-DELETE gets added to the POST automatically.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#dealing-with-ordering-and-deletion-of-forms

[Deleting form from django formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849379/deleting-form-from-django-formset)

```
def edit(request):
    Formset = formset_factory(EditForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset =  Formset(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = formset.cleaned_data
            print(cleaned_data)


        return render(request, '/edit.html', {'test': 'Post'})

    else:
        formset = Formset()

        return render(request, '/edit.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Here is part of the return formset:

data:

```
{u'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], u'form-0-test': [u'72'], u'form-0-DELETE': [u'on'], u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'0'], u'form-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'0'], u'form-0-weight': [u'1']}
```

deleted_forms:

```
[]
```

'test' and 'weight' are input values in the forms. You can see 'form-0-DELETE' there. Meaning the delete event was added to the POST with the default value 'on.' One of my links said to change this value to something that could be evaluated to true, setting it to True, true, and 1 didn't change anything.

TOTAL-FORMS is correctly 0 as I keep track of additions and deletions, but I would expected deleted_forms to be populated with form-0. This is a problem when I have more than 0 forms, as I don't know what will be in cleaned data since deleted forms aren't recorded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was on the front end. TOTAL_FORMS is the absolute total, deleted forms included. By keeping that to the correct amount, instead of subtracting -1 when deleting a form, deleted_forms was populated correctly.

Comment: Would you mind explain in a little more detail? Im having the same problem but i cant figure it out! Thanks !